# Importing module of telebot in pythonanywehere

Tags: python-3.x

I install any module of python using cmd in windows like "telebot". Pythonanywhere let us import a lot of modules without installing, like "numpy", "matplotlib" and so on. But unfortunately I can't import the module of "telebot" however I entered this command in console: pip install --user pyTelegramBotAPI

Here is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNFUN.png

And I can't import "telebot" module. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

`pip install` on PythonAnywhere by default installs to python2.7. If you were then trying to run some code in python3.7 say, then you would need to `pip3.7 install`. From your screenshot, you are using pip (2.7), and you have tagged this python3.